# Android: When does Google Play Services status invalid occur?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'd like to present the user of my app some helpful information if there is an error with Google Play Services at app initialization. 
There is

> SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
>   SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID

But when does SERVICE_INVALID occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_INVALID):

> The version of the Google Play services installed on this device is
>   not authentic.

You could just tell the user to re-install the GMS.